# Huggingface Library - Multi-document summarization

Tags: automatic-summarization, huggingface, bart

Can BART, PEGASUS ... etc. API in huggingface library be used to directly perform multi document summarization?

(e.g. here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bart.html)